# Linux apt-get upgrade hangs at update-initramfs

Tags: linux, apt-get

Running `apt-get upgrade` hangs at

> update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-7-amd64.

It's been hung for at least five hours now.

If I kill the process and try `apt-get upgrade` again, I get

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

So, I run that and it gets stuck at "Generating" again.
I'm very leary about rebooting at this time since I'm afraid something may be broken. What can I try?

Comment: anything strange in the kernel logs? (`dmesg`)

Comment: I've never actually looked at a kernel log before! But the only thing that appeared that didn't make sense to me was: Aug  3 20:09:19 web2 kernel: [8900225.266831] systemd: 29 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting